# Using the same key and IV Value for multiple encryption calls

Tags: encryption, cbc-mode

Is it insecure to use the same key and initialization vector in multiple encryption calls? Specifically with regards to AES-CBC, if I had multiple 8kB chunks, and I tried encrypting each chunk separately (essentially resetting the ciphertext XOR block each time), does this lead to insecure encryption?

I know that ECB mode has this issue since each blocksize in the plaintext will be outputted to the same ciphertext. But with 8kB chunks, am I subject to the same issues / are there other security holes that I'm not considering?

Thanks

Comment: There is a stronger variant of this called ESSIV. It still has weakness, but they're less severe than what you're proposing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is potentially insecure. The purpose of generating a new, random IV for every encryption is that it ensures that encrypting the same plaintext with the same key results in *different* ciphertexts each time.

If there's any possibility that the blocks you're encrypting are likely to be the same, then using the same key and IV for encryption will result in revealing to an attacker that you're sending the same data multiple times.